# Sort a list with element still in first position

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a String list:

```
List<String> listString  = new ArrayList<String>();
listString.add("faq");
listString.add("general");
listString.add("contact");
```

I do some processing on the list and I want to sort this list but I want "general" to always end up in first position.
Thx ;)

Comment: "general" isn't in the first position to begin with. Please clarify.

Comment: @Marcelo now that the OP has accepted an answer, the implication is that the code was right and the question was wrong, so I've edited.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I like @Petar's approach, but another approach would be to sort it using a custom Comparator that always said that "general" was before whatever it was being compared to.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>()
  {
     int compare(String o1, String o2)
     {
         if (o1.equals(o2)) // update to make it stable
           return 0;
         if (o1.equals("general"))
           return -1;
         if (o2.equals("general"))
           return 1;
         return o1.compareTo(o2);
     }
});
```

Comment: yes i just post an example but how to using a comparator that always said that "general" was before whatever ?

Comment: Do a specific `if`-statement first thing in the compare method, that checks if one of the inputs equal "general".

Comment: Actually, this might not be stable, depending on the algorithm used by Collections.sort, so you may want to test o1 and o2 for equality before comparing them to "general".

Comment: This approach can get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!".

Comment: @PavelKataykin As I mentioned in the comment immediately before yours, it might cause a problem because it's not stable, but I think if you added a `if (o1.equals(o2)) return 0;` first you'd be ok.

Answer (score 17):

Do `Collections.sort` on its `subList` instead.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
        Arrays.asList("Zzz...", "Two", "One", "Three")
    );
    Collections.sort(list.subList(1, list.size()));
    System.out.println(list);
    // "[Zzz..., One, Three, Two]"
```

#### API links

- [`subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

  - Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

---

If the special element is not at index 0, then simply put it there before you sort it as follows:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
        Arrays.asList("Four", "Five", "Zzz...", "Two", "One", "Three")
    );
    Collections.swap(list, list.indexOf("Zzz..."), 0);
    Collections.sort(list.subList(1, list.size()));
    System.out.println(list);
    // "[Zzz..., Five, Four, One, Three, Two]"
```

#### API links

- [`Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)

  - Swaps the elements at the specified positions in the specified list.

Comment: Yeah, but in his example "Zzz..." was at second position:)

Comment: I mean who said it will be always on first position as in your example code.

Comment: @Petar: that's why question needs clarification. My answer is how to sort elements of a list except the first. That is, how to sort the `subList(1,...)` of a `List`.

Comment: I actually think this is less readable than Petar's answer. In his answer it's very clear that the first item is a special case, and it's very explicit that "General" should be on top. This is undoubtedly better if you don't know what the first element will be, but otherwise I'd go for the explicit solution.

Comment: @Petar test it.  It works perfectly, assuming that the "general" is actually first, as the OP's question states (but the code doesn't show)

Comment: and if general is not the first how to do to sort this list and put general in first position ?

Comment: @extraneon: and in this answer it's very clear that you're sorting the `subList(1,...)` of a `List`. That is, you're sorting every elements but the first. It doesn't get any more readable than this. Whether or not this is what OP needs is unclear due to the `"general"` issue.

Comment: @CPerkins Where did I say poly's suggestion doesn't work if the element is in first position?

Comment: @Petar you asked how it would work. Oh, you edited your comment.  Okay then.

Comment: @Mercer: see latest revision.

Answer (score 12):

Sort the list without having "general" inside it and then add it to the beginning.

Comment: Terrible hack. Use `subList` instead, see my answer.

Comment: @poly, I disagree strongly that this is a "terrible hack".  It's very straight forward and works.

Comment: @Paul: it's terrible because it makes unnecessary structural modification (remove then add).

Comment: @poly, that would depend very much on whether this list is built once or multiple times.  If it were only built once, then it's reasonable to add everything except "general", sort it, then add "general" to the front.  It it were built multiple times, or modified after it were built, then yes, that's a bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet but it might have perfomance/memory problems for the very big lists.

```
public static List<String> sortSpecial(List<String> list, final String alwaysOnTopItem) {
    list.remove(alwaysOnTopItem);
    Collections.sort(list);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(list.size() + 1);
    result.add(alwaysOnTopItem);
    result.addAll(list);

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    listString.add("faq");
    listString.add("general");
    listString.add("contact");
    String alwaysOnTopItem = "general";
    List<String> sortedList = sortSpecial(listString, alwaysOnTopItem);
    System.out.println(sortedList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice! Question. If we want to fix the positions for the first and last elements then we can enhance the `@Paul Tomblin's` approach as like below one. Please copy the code and try it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomComparatorToFixedPosition {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Emp> empNames = new ArrayList<>();
    empNames.add(new Emp("name1"));
    empNames.add(new Emp("LastName"));
    empNames.add(new Emp("name2"));
    empNames.add(new Emp("FirstName"));
    empNames.add(new Emp("name3"));
    getSortedName(empNames).stream().forEach(emp -> System.out.println(emp.getName()));
  }

  public static List<Emp> getSortedName(List<Emp> empNames) {
    String first = "FirstName";
    String last = "LastName";
    Collections.sort(empNames, new Comparator<Emp>() {
      public int compare(Emp o1, Emp o2) {
        if (o1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(first) || o2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(last))
          return -1;
        if (o2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(first) || o1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(last))
          return 1;
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
      }
    });
    return empNames;
  }
}

class Emp {

  private String name;

  Emp(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```