# Using Comparator/Comparable in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

newbie to java. i have elements cat,dog,apple,zebra,parrot. I want to sort these elements ascending but "cat" should remain in first position. How can i implement in java using comparator/comparable?

Comment: You don't compare _elements_. You compare instances of classes. What class is `cat` an instance of?

Comment: What have you looked at? What have you tried ? Perhaps check out out to sort a collection in Java, and how to implement a comparator

Comment: This looks like what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857036/sort-a-list-with-element-still-in-first-position. There is one option where it's the element "cat" that's always first and another solution where the originally first element is always first (i.e. sort the sublist).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put them in a list and sort a `subList`.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "cat","dog","apple",
        "zebra","parrot");

Collections.sort(list.subList(1,list.size()));
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[cat, apple, dog, parrot, zebra]
```

It works because a `subList` gives a view of the list so the sort operates on that view.

If you prefer to stick with arrays, you can employ `Arrays.asList` to convert to a `List` for the `subList` sort.  This also uses the array to back the list so changes to the list are reflected in the array.  This only works for Object arrays `(e.g. String[], Integer[])` but not primitive arrays `(e.g. int[], double[])`.

```
String[] arr = {"cat", "dog", "apple","zebra","parrot"};
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(arr).subList(1,arr.length));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

The output is the same as above.